# PRO File opening

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, informatica, notepad, file-conversion

I have generated a .PRO file using Informatica which has some header rows followed by Data rows. When I am viewing the file on Linux CMD, all the rows are coming correctly. But after transferring the file on S3 bucket and then opening it throught Notepad, all the rows come as a single row. The end of row gets vanished. But if I drag and open the file in Excel, I am able to see the same file in correct format. What can be the issue and what can be the solution for this.

Comment: Linux systems normally use a line-feed character to indicate the end of a row. Windows systems use a carriage-return + line-feed

Comment: What do you mean by "transferring the file on S3 bucket and then opening it through Notepad"? How do you open an Amazon S3 object with Notepad?

Comment: Hi John Rotenstein, after transferring the file to S3. I am downloading the same file and then opening it with Notepad.

Comment: @NickW, so how can this issue be resolved? As my Source server is a Linux one and the target System is Windows.

Comment: Generate the file with Windows row terminators?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful: UNIX and Linux are just using `\n` (newline) to go to a new line, while Windows is using `\r\n` (the first one is the carriage return). When you are moving a UNIX/Linux file to a Windows environment, quite some tools or programs are converting `\n` to `\r\n` (known as the `unix2dos` command) automatically.